# How way to click a button within #shadow-root (closed) via Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

`I want to automate a web scraping. But, I couldn't click a button to resolve ReCAPTCHA with extension Buster. The button is a #shadow-root(closed).

[Button to resolve ReCAPTCHA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPpDy.png)

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from time import sleep

def setup_driver():
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    extension_path = "/home/work04/.mozilla/firefox/vyrx65nr.default-release/extensions/{e58d3966-3d76-4cd9-8552-1582fbc800c1}.xpi"
    driver.install_addon(extension_path, temporary=True)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    return driver

def recaptcha(driver):
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

   try:
       wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.button-holder:nth-child(4)')))
       shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'button-holder help-button-holder')
       shadow_element = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector("#solver-button")', shadow_host)
       shadow_root = shadow_element.shadow_root
       reCAPTCHA_button = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#solver-button')

       if reCAPTCHA_button.is_displayed():
          reCAPTCHA_button.click()
          print("Botão reCAPTCHA clicado com sucesso!")
       else:
          print("O botão reCAPTCHA não está visível na página.")

   except NoSuchElementException as erro:
      print(f"Erro: {erro}")
      print("O elemento do reCAPTCHA não foi encontrado na página, continuando sem resolver.")

  except Exception as e:
     print(f"Ocorreu um erro inesperado: {e}")`
```

How can I to do this?